App does not retrieve all bluetootj devices on Android 14 but does so on versions lower than 12 and on Windows
I am using the universal_ble flutter plugin. When I do a scan, I can see that this retrieves all the bluetooth devices I want it to on windows and on Android versions lower than 12. However, it does not do so on Android 14. It's not that it does not retrieve any device at all on 14, it just does not retrieve certain devices (which has me thinking I have set up correct permissions). The devices it does not seem to retrieve are BLE tags. However, it retrieves some other BLE tags of a different type. I do not see any difference in the way these different tags have been configured.
My permissions relating to ble are:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
 
 <!-- legacy for Android 11 or lower -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>

Does anyone have any idea what could potentially be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Remove android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" from BLUETOOTH _SCAN permission. Turn ON Location/GPS of the android device.

neverForLocation is nice because it removes the need of requesting location (especially useful in a background service), however the way it works is not completely transparent (docs only say "some" devices are filtered) so if you notice that the ones you need disappear there's no other option than giving up on that flag.
